# Comparing two columns in excel, inserting blank rows when there is a mismatch and moving associated data

Tags: excel

I have a large set of data in excel that needs to be matched by column. Specifically, the data currently looks like:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
------------------------------
100      | 100      | aaaa
200      | 300      | bbbb
300      | 400      | cccc
400      |          |
```

Ideally, I want the data to look like:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
------------------------------
100      | 100      | aaaa
200      |          |
300      | 300      | bbbb
400      | 400      | cccc
```

Answer (score 0):

If Column 1 is the reference for the other columns, than I would probably use the function vlookup.

E.g. if you have your mentioned data in Sheet1, put the following in Sheet2:

```
First column:   =Sheet1!A1
                =Sheet1!A2
                =Sheet1!A3
                etc.

Second column:  =Sheet1!B1
                =ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet1!B:C;1;FALSE);"")
                =ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet1!B:C;1;FALSE);"")
                etc.

Third column:   =Sheet1!C1
                =ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet1!B:C;2;FALSE);"")
                =ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet1!B:C;2;FALSE);"")
                etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer above worked well once I changed ISERROR to IFERROR. ISERROR returned a warning that the function contained too many arguments.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19207899)

Comment: Fine, delete it. I simply wanted to post a comment on a problem with the single posted answer, but this site only allows comments for those with 50 points, therefore the new answer post. I do not have a new question. Of the three reviewers, at least Zenoo has a clear aim ("Just trying to share some knowledge..."). Delete and live justly and happily...